# Distance between two paralllel planes

Tags: geometry

Can you find the perpendicular distance between two parallel planes by just knowing the straight line distance between any two random points, one on each plane? You also know the angle between these two points with the ground plane. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let the distance between the points be $d_0$, let the distance between the planes be $d$, and let the angle be $\alpha$. Then $\frac{d}{d0} = \sin \alpha$. The distance between the planes therefore is $d = d_0 \sin \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for replying but you are assuming both the points to be such that the 2-D plane containing both the points will be perpendicular to both the parallely planes in question.

Comment: That is not a loss of generality. There is exactly one such plane, unless the line segment connecting the two points points is perpendicular to both plane.

Comment: SinA = P/H, in your solution H is the straight-line distance between the two points and A is the angle between the two points with one axis being the same straight-line and the other axis being the ground plane. Under these assumptions it is not known that P will actually be perpendicular between the two parallel planes. It could take any shape depending upon the position of the points from each other.